# How to use TextBox text in c++ form?

Tags: c++, forms, visual-c++

I want to know is there anyone that knows how I can assign `textbox` text in C++ `windowsform` to a string?
In c# it's like for example:

```
string name;
name=textbox1.Text;
```

but in C++ I don't know how it works.
I've tried this:

```
string name;
name = name_2door_txt->Text;
```

but visual give me this error:

```
    IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::string = System::String ^
```

and I need it to be a string. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include following header file

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
```

then try

```
msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
std::string std_string= context.marshal_as<std::string>(name_2door_txt->Text);
```

If you want to convert to managed string

```
System::String^ managed_string = name_2door_txt->Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the reference of system::string you can find a few conversion functions. There is, for example, the toCharArray() function. With that you could do:

```
std::string name(name_2door_txt->Text.toCharArray());
```

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.string(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you need to make a handle (`^`) to a `System::String` object

```
System::String^ name = name_2door_txt->Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change to this:

```
    System::String^ name;
    name = textbox1->Text; // VisualC++
```

To pass the name to native/unmanaged c++

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

std::string nName = static_cast<const char*>( Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(name).ToPointer() );
callNative( nName ); // Call to C++ native
```