# Error expression must have a class type | C++

Tags: c++, clr

so basically I was on a C++ console application and it was working quite good.

but today I decided to change from console to Application form, but I am getting an error while coding a statment.

on the console application it was working just fine, but now I have to deal with textBox etc..

and this is exaclty where my error is flagged.

UI.h : this is where my textBox was created :

```
    {
    public:
        ui(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~ui()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^ panel1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button2;
    protected:
```

UI.h : where i am getting the error

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    std::string hwid = GetHardwareID();
    if (Authenticate(textBox1.c_str(), hwid.c_str())) //Edit: Authenticate is just a function to authenticate someone.
    {
    }

//Edit: The error appear heres : if (Authenticate(textBox1.c_str(), hwid.c_str())) on textBox1.

//Edit: The error is : expression must have a class type | C2228( error code)
    
}
```

why isn't this code working?

pretty sure that is a quick fix but so far I haven't figured it out yet...

thanks !

Comment: Your code sample is not exactly complete, but assuming `textBox1` is a pointer, it should be `textBox1->c_str()` (that is, if `textBox1` even has such a member)

Comment: well the thing is i tried this exact same solution you just written, but it does not work, as far as i do textBox1->c_str()  textBox1 appear correct but now c.str() is wrong.

Comment: So `textBox1->` alone is fine? What type is `textBox1`?

Comment: So to be clear, "if (Authenticate(textBox1.c_str(), hwid.c_str()))" it give error to textBox1. and "if (Authenticate(textBox1->c_str(), hwid.c_str()))" give error on c_str()

Comment: changing it to your solution get me this error : "System::Windows::Forms::TextBox" has no member "c_str"

Comment: Question is incomplete and cannot get a good answer without dumb luck and guesswork or playing comment Whack-A-Mole. Please make a [mre]. If making there MRE doesn't show you the mistake, add the MRE to the question.

Comment: So the `->` operator is correct. Now `TextBox` really does not have a `c_str`. The closest thing to that might be `TextBox::Text`, but that's a `System::String`, not an `std::string`. I'm not sure what signature your `Authenticate` has, but you might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201555/how-to-use-textbox-text-in-c-form/32201706)

Comment: i'm still completly lost with this error :D trying to figure out still

Comment: The error means that `TextBox^` is not a class (because it's a pointer) and thus it cannot be followed by a dot. The other error means that `TextBox` does not have a `c_str` method (it really doesn't - it's not an `std::string` nor is it convertible to one)

Comment: Ok thanks ill try to work in a fix for this if I can